# Jquery Post - Itunes API returns 200 and error

Tags: jquery, json, api, post, itunes

the json response is valid
http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson

but i get an error ... why?

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/36Vxs/

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson" )
    .done(function(data) { console.log(data); })
    .fail(function(data) { console.log(data); })
 });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get the error below in console. `Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` I changed it to .getJSON to make sure it wasn't a POST but it still didn't work

Comment: have you got a link for the documentation for the (public?) API?

Comment: Itunes API  Doc: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get JSON from another domain. You need to get JSONP. The following works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson",
        dataType: 'JSONP'
    })
    .done(function(data) { console.log(data); })
    .fail(function(data) { console.log(data); })
 });
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the documentation link, it tells you to use JSONP - see here http://jsfiddle.net/joevallender/rMKZw/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(
      'http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&callback=?', 
      function ( data ) {
         console.log(data)

     });
 });
```

It doesn't jump out at you through

`Note: When creating search fields and scripts for your website, you should use dynamic script tags for your xmlhttp script call requests. For example:`

`<script src="http://.../search?parameterkeyvalue&callback="{name of JavaScript function in webpage}"/>`

If you see something like that, you need to both use $.getJSON and add callback=? to your request in jQuery to invoke JSONP